# A jar contains 10 black buttons and 6 brown buttons. If 9 buttons are picked at random, what is the probability that exactly 5 of them are black?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A jar contains ten black buttons and six brown buttons. If nine buttons are picked at
random, what is the probability that exactly five of them are black?

I tried $\dfrac{\binom{10}{5}\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{16}{9}} = 0.0079.$ The answer given is $\dfrac{189}{572} = 0.3304$.

Is there another way to do this problem other than my counting argument? Is there something wrong with the way that I counted? Is the given answer a typo?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't $.0079$ seem awfully low to you? there's nothing wrong with your method;  I suggest checking your arithmetic.

Comment: It's just a calculation mistake, your combinatorial expression is correct.

Comment: There are $10$ different possible outcomes (from $0$ to $9$ black buttons).  Since the fraction of buttons that are black is $10/16=5/8=0.625$, the most likely outcome when picking $9$ buttons would seem to be that about $0.625 * 9 = 5.625$ are black... that is, either $5$ or $6$, so each of those should be expected to have probability > $1/10$.  Check your arithmetic :).

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct:
$$\frac{\binom{10}{5}\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{16}{9}} = \frac{252\cdot 15}{11440} = \frac{189}{572}$$

And there is [another equivalent approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Combinatorial_identities):
$$\frac{\binom{9}{5}\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{16}{10}} = \frac{126\cdot 21}{8008} = \frac{189}{572}$$

Comment: O my gosh! You're right! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.